# Python 'wikipedia' Module not recognized in my Virtual Environment

Tags: python, import, module, wikipedia

I have been struggling to get Wikipedia working in any way shape or form for a few days now, and while it did work briefly, it was quite brief.

[Here is the tutorial I have been following](https://stackabuse.com/getting-started-with-pythons-wikipedia-api/)

I have used pip install Wikipedia to install the module. Every time I try to do the same in any other directory besides the original (python37, python38 or any venv), I receive the following:

```
/c/Python/Python36/History
$ pip install wikipedia
Requirement already satisfied: wikipedia in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from wikipedia) (4.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from wikipedia) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->wikipedia) (1.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (1.25.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (3.0.4)
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have created a virtual environment in both Python36 as well as Python37, to no avail.

I have also removed the problem that was flagged by VSCode, which told me the module was not recognized, here is the most basic version of my code:

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    flash,
    jsonify,
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    session,
    url_for,
)
from flask_session import Session
import wikipedia

print(wikipedia.search("apple"))
```

Which returns this result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Python\Python37\HistoryArchive\env\app.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(wikipedia.search("apple"))
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 103, in search
    raw_results = _wiki_request(search_params)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 742, in _wiki_request
    return r.json()
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I have tried this using both my Python 3.6.7 and 3.7.3 interpreters, with no success.

At this point, I feel I've run out of options on what to do. Any recommendations?

Comment: Why is flask part of the minimal example? Could you please simply try to open thje python interpreter and run `import wikipedia` and `wikipedia.search("apple")`? Everything is working fine here

Comment: I've removed all references to flask but still seem to be getting the same output. Weird considering the json references.